# How to update data in access 2010 using c# in visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

Sir,
I wrote a program for update data in my MS-Access database. but It show error message box. What is my fault? How can I fix it.
I am using MS-Access 2010. Database formet (.accdb). Other Information:

1. Table Name: user_info.
2. Table's Fields are: a) Name  b) Designation  c) User_Name  d) Password.
3. Visual Studio 2019
4. C#

My Trying Code is:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Shahid_Abdul_Hamid_Hall_1._1
```

{
public partial class ChangePassword : Form

```
{
     OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    public ChangePassword(String User)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SAHHDB1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        lvl_user.Text = User;
    }

    private void ChangePassword_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void btn_change_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txt_new_pass.Text == txt_cnew_pass.Text)
        {
            try
            {

             
                     conn.Open();
                     OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                     cmd.CommandText = "update user_info set Password = '"+ txt_new_pass.Text + "' where User_Name = '"+ lvl_user.Text + "'";

                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

               conn.Close();   
            }
            catch (Exception ew)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error" + " " + ew);

            }
        } 
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("'Confirm New Password' dosen't Match 'New Password'. Try Again.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Alawal, what is the error exactly? Did you try and debug the method `btn_change_Click` - in which line of code is the error?

Comment: Please use parameters to prevent sql Injection. Try a password with a ' in it

Comment: An error message usually contains useful information about the problem. This points to the way to fix it. So it is important information  but you didn't include it

Comment: Finally Solved it. I Just remove MS Access DB. and using sql DB. In sql DB no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be best-off trying something like [LINQ Connect Express](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevartSoftware.LinqConnectExpress-LINQtoSQLSolutionforanyDatabase), and letting VS auto-generate the code.

Otherwise, your provider does not appear to be up-to-date and you changed the path so I can't see if you did that right either.  If LINQ Connect Express doesn't work, start with the snippit below.

```
        string connectionString = @ "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Your\Full\Path\Database.accdb";  

        // Create a connection    
        using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) { 
            // your code here
        }
```